# Error when deploy Laravel 5.7 on Heroku for the first time

Tags: laravel, heroku

I have a fresh installation of Laravel 5.7 and when i try to deploy it in Heroku i get an error. I have also setup the `APP-KEY` value and the `heroku/php` Buildpak in Heroku settings.

Have any idea of whats happening?

Build log:

```
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Bootstrapping...
-----> Installing platform packages...
       - php (7.3.1)
       - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)
       - apache (2.4.37)
       - nginx (1.8.1)
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 1.8.0 2018-12-03 10:31:16
       Loading composer repositories with package information
       Installing dependencies from lock file
       Package operations: 53 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
         - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.3.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.2.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing erusev/parsedown (1.7.1): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.5.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/css-selector (v4.2.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.1): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.10.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.10.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v4.2.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/routing (v4.2.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/process (v4.2.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.10.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.2.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/contracts (v1.0.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.2.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing psr/log (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/debug (v4.2.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v4.2.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/finder (v4.2.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/console (v4.2.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.7): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.1.3): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.99): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing ramsey/uuid (3.8.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing opis/closure (3.1.5): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing symfony/translation (v4.2.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.36.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing monolog/monolog (1.24.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.49): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (2.0.5): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.5.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3.3): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing laravel/slack-notification-channel (v1.0.3): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing zendframework/zend-diactoros (1.8.6): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing php-http/promise (v1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing php-http/httplug (v1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing php-http/guzzle6-adapter (v1.1.1): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing lcobucci/jwt (3.2.5): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing nexmo/client (1.6.1): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing laravel/nexmo-notification-channel (v1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing laravel/framework (v5.7.22): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing fideloper/proxy (4.1.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (v0.2): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.2.0): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.4): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing psy/psysh (v0.9.9): Downloading (100%)
         - Installing laravel/tinker (v1.0.8): Downloading (100%)
       Generating optimized autoload files
       > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
       > @php artisan package:discover --ansi

       In PackageManifest.php line 168:

         The /tmp/build_73d13e43929228fd562bd9df625e545c/bootstrap/cache directory m  
         ust be present and writable.                                                 


       Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
 !     WARNING: A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error
 !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
 !     
 !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
 !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
 !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
 !     in your 'composer.json'.
 !     
 !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
 !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
 !     
 !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
 !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
 !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
 !     
 !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
 !     
 !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
 !     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
 !     - A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
 !     Push failed
```

Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

composer.json, because a previous extra error, i add `"laravel/dusk"` to extra->laravel->dont-discover

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/dusk"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the file [`bootstrap/cache/.gitignore`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/bootstrap/cache/.gitignore) exists and is part of your repository.

Comment: @deejayoz, that works! if you set it as a solution i mark it as a solution :) I force to add the cache folder to the repo and that make it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fresh Laravel install comes with [a `bootstrap/cache/.gitignore` file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/bootstrap/cache/.gitignore). Its presence (and contents) in the respository ensures that the directory exists in a deployment, but that nothing else *within* that directory winds up in source control.

The error you're receiving indicates that you didn't check it into your repository (or removed it for some reason). Checking it in should clear up the message, as the folder will exist for your app to write to it.

There are several other instances of this, like `storage/logs`, a variety of subfolders of `storage/framework`, etc. If you receive similar errors in these directories, the same fix applies.